# Login Page is sending me to Home Page when i press system back button and without loggin

Tags: android, flutter, screen

I don't know how to deal with this, I'm new to flutter, when the app is installed(debugging mode), the logging page appears, and testing "bugs" the first thing I do is press the system button back, and it takes me to the home page, why is this happenign??????
For me, it is very rare, I am using firebase but I do not think it has anything to do that I have not yet implemented the auth system, I am only testing pages and I do not think that is the problem, I want to clarify that I am also using an inheritedWidget, that could be causing this? I'll leave the most important parts of my code below.

The codes that I put are summarized, things like containers and cards I did not put them here, cuz it would be very long.

**Login page:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:landscapes/bloc/inherited_provider.dart';
import 'package:landscapes/bloc/login_bloc.dart';
import 'package:landscapes/pages/register_page.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  LoginPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();


  //I WAS TRYING TO DO THIS TO CLEAR THE HISTORY BUT STILL DONT WORK
  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.detached) {
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Form(
      key: formKey,
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          _crearFondo(),
          _loginForm(context),
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
//BOTON INGRESAR
  Widget _button() {
    return RaisedButton(
      color: Color.fromRGBO(254, 200, 140, 1),
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 90.0, vertical: 15.0),
      child: Text('ingresar'),
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
      ),
      elevation: 0.0,
      onPressed: () => _submit(),
    );
  }

  //SUBMIT DEL BOTON
  void _submit() async {
    if (!formKey.currentState.validate()) return null;
    formKey.currentState.save();

    Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => RegisterPage()));
    // Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, HomePage.routName).then((value) { setState(() { });});
  }
```

**Register page:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:landscapes/pages/login_page.dart';

class RegisterPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RegisterPageState createState() => _RegisterPageState();
}

class _RegisterPageState extends State<RegisterPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        Navigator.of(context)
            .pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('/loginpage', (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
        return Future.value(false);
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Text('Register Page'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Home Page:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:landscapes/models/posts_model.dart';
import 'package:landscapes/widgets/snapshots_alerts.dart';
import 'package:landscapes/bloc/inherited_provider.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _drawerKey = GlobalKey();

    //HERE THE INHERITEDWIDHET GETS INITIALIZED, that could be causing this? OR not?
    final postsBloc = InheritedProvider.of(context);
    postsBloc.cargarPostsBloc();

    return Scaffold(
      key: _drawerKey,
      drawer: new Drawer(),
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        title: Text('LandScapes'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          iconMenuDrawer(_drawerKey),
          Expanded(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  streamBuilderCards(postsBloc),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/createpostpage'),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget iconMenuDrawer(GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _drawerKey) {
    return Align(
      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
      child: Container(
        height: 50.0,
        width: 50.0,
        color: Colors.red,
        child: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.menu,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          onPressed: (() => _drawerKey.currentState.openDrawer()),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget streamBuilderCards(PostsBloc postsBloc) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: postsBloc.cargarPostsBloc(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<PostModel>> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return snapshotMsgError(snapshot);
        }
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return snapshotCircularProgressIndicator();
        }
        List<PostModel> posts = snapshot.data;
        return ListView.builder(
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: posts.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            PostModel data = posts[index];
            return _crearCards(context, data, postsBloc);
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

**Update: adding main.dart
Main:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:landscapes/bloc/inherited_provider.dart';
import 'package:landscapes/pages/create_post.dart';
import 'package:landscapes/pages/home_page.dart';
import 'package:landscapes/pages/login_page.dart';
import 'package:landscapes/pages/register_page.dart';
import 'package:landscapes/pages/show_post_page.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InheritedProvider(
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Material App',
        initialRoute: '/loginpage',
        routes: {
          '/loginpage': (context) => LoginPage(),
          '/registerpage': (context) => RegisterPage(),
          '/': (context) => HomePage(),
          '/createpostpage': (context) => PostCreate(),
          '/showpostpage': (context) => ShowPostPage(),
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Add your ```main.dart```

Comment: @ikerfah i just added the main to the thread, you can see it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If in routes, you define route "/", then this route will be marked as initial route.

> If in your route ‘/’ present then it is not mandatory to defined initial route. It will make ‘/’ as your initial route and If you want your initial route different than ‘/’ then you can define.

So what I think is that you can change "/" to something like "/home" and see if it work.

Comment: Thank you, that's work. I remove all the slash and leave the routes for example like 'homepage', also replace the "pushReplacementNamed" that was in the home page to "pushNamed" where you wanted it to be possible to go back to the previous page for example homepage => createpostpage => homepage